# Semantic UI - Make Menu Bigger

Tags: semantic-ui

If you go to the Semantic UI and look at the side bar menu, e.g. http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html , the link font is quite small. What is the 'technically correct semantic UI' way to make this font bigger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Semantic UI elements will accept the following size modifiers (from smallest to largest):

1. `mini`
2. `tiny`
3. `small`
4. `large`
5. `big`
6. `huge`
7. `massive`

This also goes for menus - the side menu you're referring to has the following class: `ui vertical inverted sticky menu` so all you need to do is add `big` or `huge` to it, e.g. `ui vertical inverted sticky big menu`.